# sed command removes parent closing tag in xml file

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

Iam using sed command to replace a string with another in an xml file using below given the command.

```
sed "s/one/two/g" /data/common/codeset-mapper.xml > /data/codeset-mapper.xml
```

But the closing parent tag is getting removed. Is there a work around?

Comment: Can you show a short sample XML file in which this happens?

Comment: <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<codesets>

    <may code = "one">
 
 <code value = "4405">
                <codeset key = "701" value = "TYPEA_MSG_0001" description = "Coupon notification"/>
       </code>

    </may>

</codesets>

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Does the file have Windows line endings?

Comment: No,  it does'nt have windows line endings.

Comment: is there any other stream editor like sed?

Comment: It's much safer to use XML-aware tools to edit XML files.

Comment: If there is a blank line at the end of the file, sed command works perfectly. But if there is no blank line at the end of the code, then the parent closing tag will go missing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21115982/1030675